# Unsatisfiedlinkerror in android (eclipse)

Tags: android, eclipse, java-native-interface, android-ndk

I am trying to run a simple jni code in Android, But all I am getting Unsatisfiedlinkerror .

Here is my Java code:

```
package com.lipcap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

TextView a;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    a=new TextView(this);

    String b; 
    MainActivity ob=new MainActivity();
    b=ob.sniff();

    a.setText(b);

    setContentView(a);
}
public native String sniff();

    static{
        System.loadLibrary("native");
    }


}
```

And here is My C++ code(in $PROJECT_PATH/jni/):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
#include<jni.h>
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_lipcap_MainActivity_sniff
(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj){
       return env->NewStringUTF("This is Native");
}
```

I have complied java code using javac, and made the header using javah.

Then I ran ndk-build.
And then I ran code from eclipse.(installed apk in android).

I get this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(  769): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(  769): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: sniff
E/AndroidRuntime(  769):    at com.lipcap.MainActivity.sniff(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  769):    at com.lipcap.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:36)
E/AndroidRuntime(  769):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
E/AndroidRuntime(  769):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
E/AndroidRuntime(  769):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
E/AndroidRuntime(  769):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
E/AndroidRuntime(  769):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
E/AndroidRuntime(  769):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(  769):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(  769):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
E/AndroidRuntime(  769):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  769):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
E/AndroidRuntime(  769):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
E/AndroidRuntime(  769):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
E/AndroidRuntime(  769):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have not set LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

However,without setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH sample code such as HelloJNI provided by NDK runs absolutely fine.

Please tell me where i am missing.

Comment: `MainActivity ob=new MainActivity();` Why? you are already into an instance of  MainActivity. `this.sniff()` must be used.

Comment: Yea, this.sniff could be used.
Anyway, this does not create any difference as far as Unsatisfiedlinkerror is concerned.

Comment: Changing code from C++ to C everything works fine.. :)

Answer (score 12):

Richard-head you mentioned: *"Changing code from C++ to C everything works fine"...*

I was tortured by the exact same problem for several days and I did make sure everything typed by me (naming, Android.mk etc.) has no problem. Whenever in C, I'm fine. As long as I change to cpp, `UnsatisfiedLinkError`.

I finally got the hint from this link:
http://markmail.org/message/fhbnprmp2m7ju6lc

It's all because of the C++ name mangling! The same function, if you don't have `extern "C"` surrounding it in the .cpp file, the name is mangled so JNI can not find the function name so `UnsatisfiedLinkError` pops up.

Put on and remove the `extern "C" { }` around your functions, run `nm obj/local/armeabi/libnative.so`, you will clearly see the same function without and with name mangling.

I hope this helps others with the same problem too.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really been called quite right...

Try:

```
package com.lipcap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    TextView a;

    public native String sniff();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        a=new TextView(this);

        String b = sniff(); 

        a.setText(b);

        setContentView(a);
    }

    static{
        System.loadLibrary("native");
    }

}
```

Lastly... is this in your Android.mk?

```
LOCAL_MODULE    := native
```

Comment: Check the edit... the module name in the Android.mk should match the library name you're loading.

Comment: Moreover, Order of declaration doesnt matter in Java.

Comment: Yes..
this is in my Android.mk
LOCAL_MODULE    := native

Answer (score 0):

I will give an another advice.I got this same error before but I solved this problem via "Android Native Development Kit Cookbook".Please note these statements;

**The native function must follow a specific pattern for a package name, class name, and method name.The package and class name must agree with the package and class name of the Java class from which the native method is called, while the method name must be the same as the method name declared in that Java class.
This helps the Dalvik VM to locate the native function at runtime.Failing to follow the rule will result in UnsatisfiedLinkError at runtime.**

For example for above

You need to change your function name like (don't use com.bla in the package names if you focus on NDK)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
#include<jni.h>

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_lipcap_example_MainActivity_sniff
(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj){
       return env->NewStringUTF("This is Native");
}
```