# Getting java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError and java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: android, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I have project source as well as apk file. if i am directly installing APK on emulator then its working fine but while running the application from eclipse i am getting following errors.

```
01-12 07:45:42.918: E/AndroidRuntime(889): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-12 07:45:42.918: E/AndroidRuntime(889): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
01-12 07:45:42.918: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at com.ims.IMSClientActivity.<init>(IMSClientActivity.java:64)
01-12 07:45:42.918: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
01-12 07:45:42.918: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
01-12 07:45:42.918: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
01-12 07:45:42.918: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)
01-12 07:45:42.918: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
01-12 07:45:42.918: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
01-12 07:45:42.918: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
01-12 07:45:42.918: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-12 07:45:42.918: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-12 07:45:42.918: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
01-12 07:45:42.918: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-12 07:45:42.918: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-12 07:45:42.918: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-12 07:45:42.918: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-12 07:45:42.918: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-12 07:45:42.918: E/AndroidRuntime(889): Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
01-12 07:45:42.918: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at com.Aloha.tinyWRAP.ProxyVideoProducer.registerPlugin(ProxyVideoProducer.java:65)
01-12 07:45:42.918: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at com.Aloha.ngn.NgnEngine.initialize(NgnEngine.java:67)
01-12 07:45:42.918: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at com.ims.Engine.<clinit>(Engine.java:37)
01-12 07:45:42.918: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  ... 16 more
01-12 07:45:42.918: E/AndroidRuntime(889): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: swig_module_init
01-12 07:45:42.918: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at com.Aloha.tinyWRAP.tinyWRAPJNI.swig_module_init(Native Method)
01-12 07:45:42.918: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at com.Aloha.tinyWRAP.tinyWRAPJNI.<clinit>(tinyWRAPJNI.java:679)
01-12 07:45:42.918: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  ... 19 more
```

P.S :Some libraries are used in this project

Help me to solve this problem.

Thanks

Comment: have you add that in build path ?

Comment: yeah i have added that library in build path

Comment: error is here see Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: swig_module_init

Comment: yeah, that is the method of library if i am commenting this it will gives me error with other methods while apk is get installed properly

Comment: see this may be solve your issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6350329/unsatisfiedlinkerror-in-android-eclipse

Comment: Thanks but why that apk runs properly ? project source is too large how do i find the error ?

Comment: have you try to clean you workspace ? try it once and are you testing in emulator or real device. is that perfect api to run this APK ?

Comment: yeah i have cleaned it many times and i tested in device as well as on emulator.

Comment: may be you have to trace your code. or can you share that ?

Comment: go to profile and try it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22632/discussion-between-juned-and-chintan-khetiya)

Answer (score 1):

Your **pjsua2JNI.java** - File is in the wrong namespace/directory. You have to give it at the root of your Java sources, with following structure:

**org > pjsip > pjsua2 >** ... Files have to be here ...

Do not forget to import that package in your application code:

**import org.pjsip.pjsua2.*;**